# Similar ways of saying “You understand me?” and “You hear me?”

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction

What are some alternative ways of saying “You understand me?” and “You hear me?” as a rhetorical question that we say when we are angry and pissed. Because sometimes these expressions look overly used. Almost everybody uses these expressions when they are angry.

Also what are some not-so-strong alternatives which we might use in a not so hot situations.

Comment: _"You feel me?_ is another expression.

Comment: Capt. Thomas Fuller: *No, no not just off S.W.A.T., off the force. You **feel** me?* -- Hondo: *Oh yeah, I **feel** you.* -- [S.W.A.T. (2003)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0257076/quotes?item=qt1287575) ;-)

Comment: This is simply Too Broad. ***Okay?***

Comment: Get it?  Follow?  Catch my drift?  Getting my drift?  Am I getting through to you here?  Does that make sense?  Am I making sense?  Etc. etc.

Answer (score 5):

It's hard to get away from angry-sounding examples from cop & gangster movies.

In my head I'm hearing most of these as spoken by Denzel Washington :)

**Polite & non-confrontational** (focus on yourself & the topic rather than on the listener):

> "Am I making sense?"
>
> "Am I explaining this clearly?"

**Polite & non-confrontational,** but focus is on the listener:

> "Does that make sense [to you]?"

**Informal & non-confrontational**:

> "Did you get/catch/understand all that?"
>
> "Are we on the same page?"
>
> "Are we good?"

**Depends on volume/tone of voice**:

> "Is that clear?"
>
> "Do you understand?"
>
> "Are we understanding each other?" (this is kind of passive-aggressive)
>
> "You feel me?"
>
> "Comprendé?" (Spanish, but pretty widely understood)
>
> "Capische?" (Italian - sounds ridiculous in English conversation unless you're actually in the mafia, or saying it ironically/sarcastically).

**More common when angry**:

> "Am I making myself clear?"
>
> "Are we clear?"
>
> "You got me?"
>
> "You hear me?"

**Colloquial interjections** where you don't really care if they understand but throw this into the conversation periodically - these tend to vary by region & ethnic stereotypes:

> "See?"
>
> "You know what I'm saying?" (Mashed together sounds like "Know-um-sayn"/"numSayn"?)
>
> "Right?" "Y'know?" This is younger & more typically feminine.
>
> California's "Valley Girl" English skips these words entirely? By simply ending every statement with a rising tone? As if everything's a question?

**Outdated pop-culture reference** (spoken slowly and over-enunciated) :)

> "Do you understand the words that are comin outta my mouth?" *~Rumble in the Bronx*

Answer (score 3):

I would humbly suggest that if you have noticed that native speakers almost always use certain words in a certain context, you might sound like a native speaker if you used those words! :)

This is pretty casual/emotional language, so there's going to be a lot of variety based on local dialect. In addition to the suggestion of "you feel me?", I have also seen "Get it?" or "Got it?" used rhetorically to express high emotion/anger. In New York/New Jersey, "[capisce](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/capisce?s=t)" (from Italian, so pronounced "ka-PEESH") is sometimes used, though it might make you sound like something out of a mobster movie. "We clear?" could also be used in this context, but it's a little weaker and less common anyway.

Most of these can also be used in non-emotional situations in casual speech, just as a tag to check in with the other person in the conversation. (I have heard plenty of people saying "you feel me?" just to ensure the other person is listening.) A calm tone of voice will indicate that you aren't upset or emotionally charged about anything, but I would probably drop "me" and just say "You hear?" or "You understand?" You could also use "You know what I mean?" or the variant "Know what I mean?" (Here in New York this is frequently slurred together; it's casual speech and we talk fast, so the latter would come out "naMEAN"?)

As I said though, there's variation here. I think this is best addressed if you think about what dialect or regional language use you're trying to learn, and go from there. In addition to regional variation, you'll see a lot of class and (in the US at least) racial variation in usage here too. If you live in or near a particular language community already, it would be helpful to eavesdrop--pay close attention to the expressions that are actually used where you are and by the people you want to sound like.

Comment: and also *is it clear?*, but voice tone also matters